# Consolidate Typeahead / JSON data source in Twiiter Bootstrap v2?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple fields that need the new Typeahead feature from BS2.  Rather than repeating the data for every field I have on the form, I'd like to consolidate it into one place, likely the JS file.  I'm just not sure on the exact syntax.

Here's what I have for one of my fields:

`<input data-provide="typeahead" data-items="6" data-source='["4","4.5","5","5.5","6","6.5","7","7.5","8","8.5","9","9.5","10","10.5","11","11.5","12","12.5","13","13.5","14","14.5","15","15.5","16","16.5","17","17.5","18","18.5","19","19.5","W5","W5.5","W6","W6.5","W7","W7.5","W8","W8.5","W9","W9.5","W10","W10.5","W11","W11.5","W12","W12.5","W13","W13.5","W14","1Y","1.5Y","2Y","2.5Y","3Y","3.5Y","4Y","4.5Y","5Y","5.5Y","6Y","6.5Y","7Y","1C","1.5C","2C","2.5C","3C","3.5C","4C","4.5C","5C","5.5C","6C","6.5C","7C","7.5C","8C","8.5C","9C","9.5C","10C","10.5C","11C","11.5C","12C","12.5C","13C","13.5C","OS","N/A"]' name="size1" type="text" class="span1" autocomplete="off">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typeahead feature in Bootstrap is actually just jQuery UI's `autocomplete` feature

Skip the `data-provide` attribute, and initialize the fields yourself. You should be able to just say

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  source: [ ... your array ... ]
});
```

That's what [Bootstrap's own docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) say, and it matches [jQuery UI's docs for Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: Thanks - I stared so long at the page, I missed the source property.  And the tip about JQuery UI is also very helpful!

Comment: @Flambino what's the meaning of skip the data-provide attribute ? 

the example in bootstrap docs is this:

<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead">

when we remove it should i add a class with that script code:

<input type="text" class="typehead">

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('/typeahead', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data.options);
        });
    }
});

Comment: @Flambino it would be perceft if you can add a jsfiddle to your answer

Comment: @motto I hope you understand that I have no intention or desire to update a 6-month old answer - especially since it's still valid. See jQuery's docs instead. Their demo works the same as the above.